# React JS display an array of objects to fit the screen

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, react-grid-layout

I am new to JS and styling everything but I have created a component that takes in a variety of text from a txt document as well as a slew of images.

In my app.js, I am using a loop to input all of my data and create a list of objects. When I return the list, everything displays spaced vertically, but I would like the elements to display side by side if the browser can handle it.

If I have 15 elements and 3 of them can fit side by side on the screen, it would be 3 columns of 5, otherwise 2 columns would be contain 8 elements and 7 elements and so on and so forth.

I know of both flex boxes and react grid, but after experimenting I haven't had luck.

Does anyone have any advice?

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/jpsommer/Rotmg-Project/draft/amazing-moser?file=%2FREADME.md&workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253A%2522clbll4ngy00317mf38rxi8lgz%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522spaces%2522%253A%257B%2522clblm34940010356g09vbrt6h%2522%253A%257B%2522key%2522%253A%2522clblm34940010356g09vbrt6h%2522%252C%2522name%2522%253A%2522Default%2522%252C%2522devtools%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522currentSpace%2522%253A%2522clblm34940010356g09vbrt6h%2522%252C%2522spacesOrder%2522%253A%255B%2522clblm34940010356g09vbrt6h%2522%255D%257D)

Comment: can you send a codesandbox or somthing

Comment: you need to show code this types of questions will get you blocked from asking try to organize your self , show code , make a sandbox , debug your code and then state your issue... I mean it in a good way.

Comment: I added a code sandbox link, please let me know if it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote all you need in the description above, one way to create a grid of elements that will automatically adjust to the size of the browser is to use CSS Flexbox. With Flexbox, you can create a container element that holds all of your items, and then use the display: flex and flex-wrap: wrap properties to automatically arrange the items in a flexible grid. I think it's that simple.

Comment: In my app.css, I have display:flex; and flex-wrap:wrap; Is there anything else I should need to get it to work?

Comment: @JimmySommer I would have to see it to confirm it. Can you edit your question?

Comment: @mnelotti I had already added it to the original post